# Getting error: GET 404 (Not Found) when i deploy my socketio app.js on cpanel

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io, cpanel

Im trying to deploy a nodejs app on my host cpanel but whenever i try to run it the html opens but the data is not being sent from nodejs to the client side, i just get this error on the console

index.js:83
GET http://streamedbot.xyz/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=OFQdTfs 404 (Not Found)

this is my app.js

```
const fetchP2PData = require("./fetchP2PData.js");
const app = require("express")();
const path = require("path");
const Datastore = require("nedb");
// const http = require("http").createServer(app);
// const io = require("socket.io")(http);
const { createServer } = require('http')
const { Server } = require('socket.io')



const server = createServer(app)
const io = new Server(server, {
 cors: { 
    origin: "*",
methods: ["GET", "POST"],
credentials: false,
transports: ['websocket', 'polling'],
},
allowEIO3: true
})

app.get('/bkpapp/', function(req,res){
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});
let prices = [];
let openingPrice = 0 ;
const priceDb = new Datastore("./price.db");
 priceDb.loadDatabase();

 priceDb.find({}, { time: 1, value: 1, _id: 0 }, function (err, docs) {
  docs.reverse();
  prices = docs;
  console.log(prices);
});

setInterval(function () {
  (async function () {
    
let totalPrices = []; 

    const firstPage = await fetchP2PData(1, "ETB", "BUY", "USDT", null);

    if (firstPage && firstPage.success) {
      const totalPages = Math.ceil(firstPage.total / 20);
      const pagesToRun = new Array(totalPages - 1).fill(null);
      const totalElements = await pagesToRun.reduce(async (prev, _, idx) => {
        const accData = await prev;
        const page = idx + 2;

        const pageResult = await fetchP2PData(page, "ETB", "BUY", "USDT", null);
        if (pageResult && pageResult.success) {
          return [...accData, ...pageResult.data];
        }
        return accData;
      }, Promise.resolve(firstPage.data));
      totalElements.map((obj) => {
        totalPrices.push(parseFloat(obj.adv.price));
      });
    }

    
    let currentPrice = ((totalPrices[0]+totalPrices[1]+totalPrices[2]+totalPrices[3]+totalPrices[4]+totalPrices[5]+totalPrices[6]+totalPrices[7]+totalPrices[8]+totalPrices[9]+totalPrices[10])/11)-3.95;
    const d = new Date();
    if(d.getHours() == 00 && d.getMinutes() == 00){
      openingPrice = currentPrice;
     }

    let dailyPercentage = ((currentPrice - openingPrice)/openingPrice)*(100)
    prices.push({ time: d.getTime()/1000, value: (((totalPrices[0]+totalPrices[1]+totalPrices[2]+totalPrices[3]+totalPrices[4]+totalPrices[5]+totalPrices[6]+totalPrices[7]+totalPrices[8]+totalPrices[9]+totalPrices[10])/11)-3.95)})
   
    io.on('connection', sock => {
        
      })

      if(totalPrices != null){
       io.sockets.emit('price', prices)
       priceDb.insert({ time: d.getTime()/1000, value: (((totalPrices[0]+totalPrices[1]+totalPrices[2]+totalPrices[3]+totalPrices[4]+totalPrices[5]+totalPrices[6]+totalPrices[7]+totalPrices[8]+totalPrices[9]+totalPrices[10])/11)-3.95)});
       io.sockets.emit('dailyPercentage', dailyPercentage)
      }
      
    // io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket){
    //     io.sockets.emit('price', { time: d.getTime(), value: totalPrices[0] });
    // })
    
    
    console.log(prices);
  })();
}, 10000);

server.listen(3000, function(){
    console.log('listening to 80')
})
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems necessary to merge the io instance and the server instance.

According to the socket.io docs you can merge the two instances by adding line `io.attach(server);`.

[socket.io docs](https://socket.io/docs/v4/server-api/)